# Old badges appearing in profile

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

Still uses the old icons.

[image: Badges section of the profile view]

Answer (score 2):

If you look at another site with custom badge icons, such as Academia, you'll see this as well.  As such, I don't believe this is a bug.

Comment: It just means it's a network-wide bug. Still a bug.

Comment: @Mast: Maybe it was still intended.

Comment: That maybe doesn't sound certain enough to instantly hit it with [meta-tag:status-bydesign]. Just my 2c.

Comment: If it is network-wide, it should be on Meta.SE, not Meta.CR.

Comment: No sense in not fixing it now that CR has a theme.  Perhaps @Pawel can escalate the issue to Meta.SE.